# Code for linux date YYY-M-D

Tags: linux, date

In the linux date command, I use this code:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

sample output YYYY-MM-DD, such as 2016-09-05.

If I want output date YYYY-M-D, such as 2016-9-5, what should I do with this code?

Comment: In short, **don't** as the parseable format often requires _two_ digits for month and day.  A leading zero is a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%-m-%-d")
```

Explaining, the `-` will remove the leading zeros...

Example:

```
September month...

%m returns 09
%-m returns 9
```

Comment: A simple bit of explanation such as the source or description of your format string could greatly improve the quality of your answer, e.g. see `man 1 date`, `-      (hyphen) do not pad the field`, A quality answer usually brings additional votes.

Comment: Thanks, David! I will do that.

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado Much better and worthy of an additional vote. When answering, always remember you step into the role of the teacher. Making sure the questioner learns why he is doing something is just as important as being able to do it. (e.g. *give a man a fish -- feed him for a day, teach a man to fish -- feed him for life...*)

Comment: Nice words, David. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 1):

I am not user you can do that `date`, but you fix it afterwards:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
TODAY="${TODAY//-0/-}"
```